# Modifying a sub query to display a result based on "greater value"

Tags: sql

I currently have the following SQL query that lists all the names of all employees who work in a department that employs an analyst.

```
SELECT ename
FROM emp
WHERE deptno IN (SELECT DISTINCT emp.deptno
                 FROM emp, dept
                 WHERE emp.deptno = dept.dept
                 AND job = 'Analyst');
```

How do I modify it so that it displays the names of all employees who work in a department that employs two or more analysts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify subquery with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

```
SELECT emp.deptno
FROM emp, dept
WHERE emp.deptno = dept.dept AND job = 'Analyst'
GROUP BY emp.deptno HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Sorry, `HAVING` must always be the last clause

Comment: @methuselah - `It doesn't work` is an awful response. At least include ***why*** it doesn't work; wrong behaviour, error messages, etc. *[Also, note that Vasart suggested this as a change to just the sub-query, not a replacement for the entire query...]*

Comment: Sorry for the bad response @Dems. It was giving a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY` to get a count of analysts for each department, then filter the employees based on this count:

```
SELECT emp.ename
FROM 
emp, (
    SELECT emp.deptno, count(*) as analyst_count
        FROM emp, dept
        WHERE emp.deptno = dept.dept
        AND job = 'Analyst'
        GROUP BY emp.deptno
) foo
WHERE emp.deptno = foo.deptno
AND foo.analyst_count >= 2;
```